# Read more link not working

Tags: posts, permalinks, links

I having a news page it's displays all posts i have read more  each associate with different links but in some read more doesn't show links properly please refer

link

second and third post can any one tell me how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Comment: i am just doing like in the post <a href="http://www.hoteliermiddleeast.com/23571-skai-dubai-upgrades-jumeirah-village-circle-hotel/">READ MORE</a>

Comment: The HTML for the link is really weird, please post the code you are using to generated the link so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: Your edit makes less sense than the OP. I ask again, please post your code, and not in comments, it is unreadable and makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using wordpress on your website...To add read more text u just need to use the wordpress visual editor.

[image]

In this the 12 no. button is used to add read more text...Use this to add read more, there may be possibility that while adding code you are making some error..

Comment: Do not spam. You will get blocked for that. Do not use answers to post links back to your site. Thanks

Comment: Ok I was not spamming... Didn't knew about that, BTW the answer I posted helped someone ... It was not spam... If it would have been something to just get backlink and false answer u could have blamed me

Comment: I'm not blaming you, neither do I intend to fight with you :-). I just removed the links in all your posts, the system will pick up a patern and will punish you for spamming even if this wasn't your attention. Make sure that if you post links that those links are relevant to your answer and the question. Because your answer seemed helpful, I did not flag it as spam, and just rather removed your links as it is not relevant to your answer. Please keep that in mind. Remember, someone that is not as open minded like me could have flagged it, earning you minus 2 and possibility of deletion :-)